# How can I print "No" if there is no prime number found?

Tags: c++

I have been trying to print all prime numbers between two given integers, however I am having difficulty printing "No" if no prime number is found. I tried it with counting, but it turned out to be futile as I want to print "No" once only when there no prime number found between two integers.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num1, num2, count = 0, x, i;
    cin >> num1 >> num2;

    for (x = num1; x <= num2; x++) {
        for (i = 2; i <= x; i++)
            if (x % i == 0)
                break;
        if (i == x){
            cout << x << endl;
            count++;
        }
        if (count > 0)
            cout << "No" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bring the test outside of the loop and also change the condition:

```
for(x=num1;x<=num2;x++){
    for(i=2;i<=x;i++)
        if(x%i==0)
            break;
    if(i==x){
        cout<<x<<endl;
        count++;
    }
}
if(count == 0) {
    cout<<"No"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for readability to create sub-function.
It also allows to separate the concern, to test individually, (unit tests).

First:

```
bool is_prime(int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= x; i++)
       if (x % i == 0)
            break;
    return i == x;
}
```

Your loop becomes (issue seems more easy to spot):

```
for (x = num1; x <= num2; x++) {
    is (is_prime(x)){
        cout << x << endl;
        count++;
    }
    if (count > 0)
        cout << "No" << endl;
}
```

and to go further:

```
int print_primes_in_range(int num1, int num2)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int x = num1; x <= num2; x++) {
        if (is_prime(x)){
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
            count++;
        }
        // Should not be there, we only display primes in that function
        // if (count > 0)
        //    cout << "No" << endl;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Note: You can now reuse same variable name to iterate instead of having different names.

To have main as:

```
int main(){
    int num1, num2;
    cin >> num1 >> num2;

    int count = print_primes_in_range(num1, num2);
    // moved there: Only called once now :)
    if (count > 0)
         cout << "No" << endl;
}
```

It seems now really trivial that the condition is wrong, you want `count == 0`:

Final code:

```
bool is_prime(int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= x; ++i)
       if (x % i == 0)
            break;
    return i == x;
}

int print_primes_in_range(int num1, int num2)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = num1; i <= num2; ++i) {
        if (is_prime(i)){
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;

    int count = print_primes_in_range(num1, num2);
    if (count == 0)
         std::cout << "No" << std::endl;
}
```

- [Demo with primes](https://ideone.com/VXhzDc)
- [Demo without primes](https://ideone.com/nEUOJj)